# GAE running Debian won't load local resources

Tags: php, google-app-engine, drupal-7

I am running GAE SDK under Debian, app engine loads the PHP files fine, but when I bring my CMS into the picture and starts pulling on local resources, GAE says the local files are not loaded -- yet external resources like YUI and Google fonts are fine???

What would cause appengine to fail to load LOCAL resources? File permissions are fine, files exists, Apache running on the same directory loads everything as expected...any ideas???

The files are 404'ing[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine does not serve a file directly to the browser unless explicitly told to do so.  You can tell App Engine which files to serve in this way using configuration in your `app.yaml` file.  This configuration tells App Engine which files to serve and what their URLs should be:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

This example tells App Engine that all files in the `static/...` directory should be served in this way when a user requests it on the corresponding `/static/...` URL.  Instead of mapping an entire directory like this, you can also map individual files with the `static_files:` handler description.  More information on configuring static files: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

It is common to use the static files feature to serve JavaScript, CSS, and image files.  Just be sure to get the URLs to match the ones expected by the rest of your Drupal application.  You can test the resource URLs directly in your browser with the App Engine development server.